# Upload music files on YouTube

Tags: youtube

I am looking for a YouTube solution or external web application that will allow me to upload music files on YouTube by combining them with picture(s).

As far as I can see there is no support provided by YouTube to upload custom music files but just to use the existing ones from the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this site. Tried it. Seems to work - http://www.mp32u.net/

Comment: Excellent service. Does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Youtube used to have such a feature, but I think it was removed recently (since I did create a music video just using Youtube itself a few months back).

I used [WeVideo](http://www.wevideo.com/) back then in Youtube, using the Youtube Create feature. You might want to consider using this (since it is free up to a certain point).

Of course, if you do not necessarily need to have an online version of creating music videos, you can just use the Windows Live Movie Maker, it's free and is reasonable for creating basic music videos.